# Heroku router logging format

Tags: python, logging, heroku, flask

I've recently deployed a Flask app on Heroku. It provides an API on top of an existing API and requires a confidential API key for the original service from the user. The app is really just a few forms, the values of which are passed with ajax to a specific URL on the server. Nothing fancy. I take steps to not store confidential information in the app and want no traces of it anywhere within the app.

Looking at the logs from `heroku logs --source heroku`, the heroku router process stores all HTTP requests for the app, including those requests that include the confidential information.

Is there a way to specify the log format for the `heroku` process so as to not store the URL served?

Comment: Is the confidential information in the URL itself or simply in the POST data being sent in?

Comment: The confidential info is in the URL that the ajax hits.

Comment: In that case, could you use some sort of key to encode the data before adding it to the URL and decoding it when it hits the server? That way, the information isn't in cleartext in the logs. Something like a signature with a nonce and a shared secret key should work. Doesn't answer the question, but might be a solution to your concern.

Comment: Don't put sensitive information in the URL or as GET params :) If it's something like a user-id, you should be using other authentication as well. If it's something like a username/password, you should be using POST.

Comment: Have you asked Heroku support?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As other commenters mentioned, it is a bad practice to put confidential info in a URL. These could get cached or logged by a number of systems (e.g. routers, proxy servers, caches) on the roundtrip to the server. There are a couple ways to solve this:

- Put them in a the [`Authorization` header](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication). This is probably the most common way authentication is handled for REST-based APIs.
- Put them in the POST body. This works to get it out of the URL, but is a little weird semantically to say that your are POSTing the credentials to some resource (if this a REST API), unless it is a login call.

Comment: I've since refactored app to use POST requests.

Comment: While in general I can't disagree that putting confidential info in a URL can be risky, on an HTTPS connection the url parameters are encrypted.  For something like an API, url params can make a lot of sense. However, I still don't have an answer on how to filter them from the heroku router logs.